# Solving recurrence equation with triple convolution

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I'm trying to solve the following recurrence equation.

$$a_0 = 1,\hspace{5mm} a_n = \frac{1}{6}(n+1)(n+2) - \frac{1}{3} \sum_{\substack{0 \leq i,j < n,\\1 \leq i+j \leq n}} a_i a_j a_{n-i-j}$$

I started by considering the edge case $n=0$ and ended up with:
$$a_n = \frac{1}{6}(n+1)(n+2) - \frac{1}{3} \sum_{\substack{0 \leq i,j < n,\\1 \leq i+j \leq n}} a_i a_j a_{n-i-j} + \frac{2}{3}[n=0].$$

Let $A(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_nx^n$ be the ordinary generating function of $a_n$. I tried to use the approach similar to solving recurrence equation for Catalan numbers and assumed $[A(x)]^3 = \sum_{n \geq 0}\sum_{\substack{0 \leq i,j < n,\\1 \leq i+j \leq n}} a_i a_j a_{n-i-j} \hspace{1mm} x^n$ because it is a triple convolution of $A(x)$. Next, I multiplied the original equation by $x^n$ and summed it over n:
$$A(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0}\frac{1}{6}(n+1)(n+2)x^n-\frac{1}{3}[A(x)]^3+\frac{2}{3}.$$

I know that $\frac{1}{6}(n+1)(n+2) = \frac{1}{3}\binom{n+2}{2}$. Using formula for generating functions for sequences of this kind, I arrived at:

$$A(x) = \frac{1}{3(1-x)^3} - \frac{1}{3}[A(x)]^3 + \frac{2}{3}.$$

However, I cannot solve this final equation and find the expression for $A(x)$. How can I move forward in solving this recurrence equation?

Comment: The right hand side contains terms that only depend on $a_j$ for $j<n$ and the term $2a_n$, so one can solve this recursively with $a_1=3/5$, $a_2=123/125$, $a_3=3901/3125$, $a_4=20433/15625$, $a_5=2277777/1953125$ $a_6=45105661/48828125$. If the general $A(x)$ is the root of a cubic polynomial, the general from is not nice but obtained with the usual Cardano formula.

Comment: How did you simplify this recurrence equation? I am trying to solve this without compter assistance and it looks really complicated.

Comment: Your assumption that $A(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nx^n$ leads to $A^3=\sum_{n\ge 0}\sum_{i,j..}a_ia_ja_{n-i-j}x^n$ is erroneous. Assuming $a_0=1$ that formula would yield $A^3=1+2a_1x+(3a_1^2+2a_2)x^2+\cdots$ whereas the correct one would start $A^3=1+3a_1x+(3a_1^2+3a_2)x^2+\cdots$

Comment: You're right, the assumption was wrong but $\sum_{n \geq 0} \sum_{i,j..}a_i a_j a_{n-i-j} x^n$ is actually equal to $(3a_{1}^{2})x^2 + (a_{1}^{3} + 6a_1 a_2)x^3 + ...$, because there's a strict inequality from above that restricts indices $i,j$, which is $i,j < n$.

Comment: My sequence of fractional values was wrong and based on the assumption that $0\le i,j\le n$, whereas the first equation in the question is actually excluding $i=n$ or $j=n$, $0\le i,j<n$. Using the correct upper limits gives indeed $a_n=1$ $\forall n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find an error in my derivations. Let $E(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} \sum_{\substack{0 \leq i,j < n,\\1 \leq i+j \leq n}} a_i a_j a_{n-i-j} \hspace{1mm} x^n. \hspace{2mm}$ $[A(x)]^3 \neq E(x)$, as correctly pointed out by @R. J. Mathar. It is due to the fact that there's a strict inequality that restricts indices $i,j$ from above, that is $i,j < n$.

$$[A(x)]^3 = E(x) + 3A(x) - 2$$

We can rearrange this expression algebraically to get:

$$-\frac{1}{3}E(x) = -\frac{1}{3}[A(x)]^3 + A(x) - \frac{2}{3}$$

Now, we can go back to the original recurrence equation, multiply it by $x^n$ and sum over n:

$$A(x) = \frac{1}{3(1-x^3)}-\frac{1}{3}E(x) + \frac{2}{3}$$

Let's substitute for $-\frac{1}{3}E(x)$:

$$A(x) = \frac{1}{3(1-x^3)}-\frac{1}{3}[A(x)]^3 + A(x) - \frac{2}{3} + \frac{2}{3}$$

From this it is clear, that:

$$[A(x)]^3 = \frac{1}{(1-x)^3} \Leftrightarrow A(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$$

This finally means that $a_n = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

We can use hyperbolic functions to get a reasonably compact form for the generating function, but still it will be a bit messy to implement.

Begin by rearranging the equation algebraically:

$[A(x)]^3+3A(x)=\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^3}+2.$

Then define $A(x)=2\sinh u$ whereupon the left side becomes $2\sinh (3u)$, and then

$A(x)=2\sinh\left[\dfrac13\sinh^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{2(1-x)^3}+1\right)\right].$

Comment: Do you know how to solve the original recurrence equation using this generating function? Maybe I messed up in my calculations and that's why the function is quite messy. If you could double-check my derivations or propose alternative approach to solvng the recurrence equation, I would really appreciate it.